# Disabling dates with jQueryMobile and Mobiscroll

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, datetimepicker, mobiscroll

I need to disable dates e.g. weekends and holidays on a jQueryMobile date picker similar to the jQuery datePicker http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-beforeshowdate.

I'm using Mobiscroll http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/ where there are no date restrictions. Is it possible to restrict dates with mobiscroll?

My question is: what is the best approach to disabling dates for a smart phone datepicker (including mobiscroll and other options)?

Answer (score 0):

DateBox in calendar mode works ([DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/calbox.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to validate on the onSelect event? If it's not a valid selection, pop a message or something.

EDIT: Starting from mobiscroll 2.0 you can disable (make them un-selectable) date with the *invalid* option.

Check out the documentation for more info: http://docs.mobiscroll.com

EDIT:
Disable recurring days like days of week, or recurring dates with daysOfMonth, or exact dates by passing a Date object.

```
$('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
    invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'] }
});
```